# Creating polygons layer from point layer with conveks buffer

Tags: qgis, point, polygon-creation, convex-hull

I have a point layer of >750000 points representing dwellings with district heating.

Now, I want to create polygons for every n of points with a distance of n meters to the next point.

I have a polygon layer from a municipality, but the polygons are wrong in some places.
[image]

The points outside the dotted-polygon, should have a polygon of themselves. Note this is only a very small fraction of the data.

Also there are polygons where there are no points intersecting.
[image]

So, my question is:
Is there somehow a function or something else, which can create the polygons for every eg. >=5 points with a distance og eg. 10 meters to the next point?

I have tried working it out with the convex hull function, but it doesn't do the trick, because I have to select the points by hand, it that process will take ages for the whole dataset.

I'm using QGIS 2.6

Comment: You can use the Vector>Research Tools>Select by Location to select those points that intersect with a polygon within your polygon layer. Than switch selection and save selected to a new layer. Using convex hull than will create polygons only for points that are not within a polyogn.

Comment: Thanks. But the real problem is that the polygon layer I already have is not sufficient enough. I need to make a new polygon layer, as described above.

Comment: Take a look at the [DBSCAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN) or [OPTICS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OPTICS_algorithm) algorithm. I don't think, there is anything in QGIS, but there is a library in R, so it may need some intermediate steps.

Comment: @yrmirsson, thanks! I'll look into it. I also have access to AcrMap. Is there any functions here I could use?

Comment: Maybe .. but i don't know. I don't have access to the ESRI package ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

- Install [R](http://www.r-project.org/), and if you want a (slightly) more GUI style [R-Studio](http://www.rstudio.com/)
- Open R (Studio) and run this script (modify to your need) (there is an option to run it step-by-step, if you prefer):

  ```
  # install dbscan package
  install.packages("fpc")

  # load library
  library(fpc)

  # set plots bg-color
  par(bg="grey80")

  # import your point data
  data = read.csv("/home/ymirsson/R/projects/DBSCAN_Test/point_sample.csv",sep=";",header=T)

  # create a working object
  data2=data

  # delete all variables you do not want to be used to cluster the points
  data2$ID = NULL

  # plot points
  plot(data2)

  # run DBSCAN clustering
  ds <- dbscan(data2, eps=100, MinPts=3, showplot=1)

  # create a vector with the cluster prediction
  pre <- predict(ds,data2)

  # join the prediction to your base data-object
  exp <- data.frame(data,pre)

  # export
  write.table(exp, "/home/ymirsson/R/projects/DBSCAN_Test/point_sample_clustered.txt", sep="\t")
  ```

  **Note: The clustering will take a lot of time .. so it may be better to experiment with a smaller sample until you have your paramters for eps/min-points.**
- Import your clustered points in QGIS
- Select only those with "pre">0 (b/c there **will** be outliers, and they will screw up your polygons ;) )
- Run Vector>Geoprocessing Tools>Convex Hulls, with only your selected points and set your cluster-variable
  [image]
  Will look smth. like this:
  [image]
  [image]
  or zoomed:
  [image]
- You may want to extend the borders with a buffer:
  [image]

Please note:

- I'm not aware of a QGIS implementation of dbscan or a c&p python script .. but that doesn't mean it doesn't exist, so maybe you can skip the R part ;)
- I'm more of a "fun user" in R, and mostly for data statistics. There may be a better script and maybe you can create the polygons in R .. i don't know.

**EDIT:**
The surrounding borders of the convex hulls are very rough, so i propose an improvement idea:
This shows the "current" state of the resulting polygons, which include a lot of unnecessary empty space:
[image]
Idea:
In a subsequent step mark the outlining points and ID them (counter)clockwise:
[image]
Create a line vector with one of the "point 2 line/path" plugins:
[image]
And convert it into a more suitable polygon (incl. a buffer):
[image]
Comparison:
[image]
I'm not aware of a plugin to fetch the outline-points, but i think it wouldn't be *that* hard to write a little script.

Comment: Awesome!!! It worked perfectly for the test data (n=6679) Thanks!

Comment: Gave it a little more thought .. see edit for a slightly better(?) approach.

Comment: Hmm, looks very interesting. I'll look into it. Thanks!

Comment: The Concave Hull plugin might work for the "nicer" polygons: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/concavehull/

Actually, it offers clustering as well so it might be a fully working alternative to the R workflow.

Comment: That really does the trick, at least for the polygons. Nice, thx :)